# Use callbacks in node js function to retain the values from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, loops, callback

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var thenJade = require('then-jade');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: '',
database: 'nodejs'
});

exports.players_list = function(req, res) {

var data = {title: "", res: {}};
if (authenticate(req, res)) {

    results_aaa(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        res.render('players/players', {title: 'Players List', res:   result});
    });

} else {
        req.session.error = 'Please login to continue.';
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
};

function results_aaa(callback) {
    teams(function(res) {
        callback(res)
    });
}

function teams(callback) {
    var response = [];
    var query = connection.query("select * from team", function(err, result, fields) {
         var response = [];
        for (var index in result)
        {
            players(result[index].id, function(results) {                
                response.push(results);
            });
        }
        console.log(response);
        callback(response);        
    });
}

function players(id, callback) {
    query("SELECT * FROM players where team = " + id, function(results) {
        callback(results);
    });
}

function query(sql, callback) {
    connection.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
        callback(results);
    });
}
```

Here i need to fetch the players acording to their respective eams. But in for loop, im getting only first iteration values. since for async behavior, the second and third iteration values are coming after data is sent to view. Please Help

```
[ { id: 2, player_name: 'Virat Kohli', team: '1' },
  { id: 4, player_name: 'A B DeVilliers', team: '1' },
  { id: 6, player_name: 'Chris Gayle', team: '1' } 
    GET /players 200 177ms - 556
[ { id: 7, player_name: 'Ajinkya Rahane', team: '2' },
  { id: 8, player_name: 'Shane Watson', team: '2' },
  { id: 9, player_name: 'Stuart Binny', team: '2' },
  { id: 10, player_name: 'Karun Nair', team: '2' },
  { id: 11, player_name: 'Sanju Samson', team: '2' } ]
[ { id: 1, player_name: 'Virender Sehwag', team: '3' },
  { id: 3, player_name: 'David Miller', team: '3' },
  { id: 5, player_name: 'Shaun Marsh', team: '3' } ]
GET /css/bootstrap.min.css 304 5ms
GET /css/bootstrap.css 304 4ms
GET /css/style.css 304 4ms
```

As you can see,after first iteration, the view is rendered. How to use callbacks to wait untill the forloop finishes its execution so that i will get all result sets.

Please Help

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
    var async = require('async');
var mysql = require("mysql");
var thenJade = require('then-jade');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'nodejs'
});

exports.players_list = function(req, res) {

    var data = {
        title: "",
        res: {}
    };
    if (authenticate(req, res)) {

        results_aaa(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            res.render('players/players', {
                title: 'Players List',
                res: result
            });
        });

    } else {
        req.session.error = 'Please login to continue.';
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
};

function results_aaa(callback) {
    teams(function(err,res) {
        callback(res);
    });
}

function teams(callback) {
    var response = [];
    var query = connection.query("select * from team", function(err, result, fields) {
        var tasks = [];
        result.forEach(function(team) {
            tasks.push(function(callback1) {
                players(item.id, callback1);
            });
        });
        async.parallel(tasks, function(error, response) {
            callback(null, response);
        });
    });
}

function players(id, callback) {
    query("SELECT * FROM players where team = " + id, function(error,results) {
        callback(error,results);
    });
}

function query(sql, callback) {
    connection.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
        callback(error,results);
    });
}
```

Comment: HI... Im getting null in console.log() in players_list function.

Comment: Hi... I made some small necessary changes, n it worked... Thank You:)

Answer (score 0):

I understand where you are coming from with callbacks. The issue occurs inside of the 'team' function. Your callback is called while your 'for' loop is still running. You would need to find a way to execute the callback AFTER all of the 'player' queries are finished.

```
function teams(callback) {
    var response = [];
    var query = connection.query("select * from team", function(err, result, fields) {
        var response = [];
        for (var index in result)
        {
            players(result[index].id, function(results) {                
                response.push(results);
            });
        }
        console.log(response);
        // The loop will continue the run... (because the queries take longer)
        // the callback is executed BEFORE the loop is finished running
        callback(response);        
    });
}
```

**Solution 1:**
Look into [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/). The way the queries are structured prevents you from using callbacks to produce your intended result.

**Solution 2:**

If you are looking to grab all players by their respective teams, you only need one query on the players table to achieve the desired output. Please take a look at the query/example below (Select query with ORDER BY).

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var thenJade = require('then-jade');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'nodejs'
});

var getPlayersByTeam = function(callback) {
  // New query
  var playerQuery = "SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY team ASC"; 

  connection.query(playerQuery, function(err, result, fields) {
    callback(results);
  });

};

var players_list = function(req,res){
  var data = {
    title: "", 
    res: {}
  };

  if (authenticate(req, res)) {
    getPlayersByTeam(function(result){
      res.render('players/players', {title: 'Players List', res: result});
    });
  } else {
    req.session.error = 'Please login to continue.';
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
};

exports.players_list = players_list;
```